# Hi, is there a way to install an updated version of an application alongside the old version of the application

Tags: installation

is there a way to install an updated version of an application alongside the old version of the application (i.e., without uninstalling the old version)?

Comment: what OS? Which application?

Comment: any application and any os.........how?

Comment: Too vague.  You need to provide some parameters, otherwise the only reasonable answer is "Maybe.  It depends."

Answer (score 1):

Also, look into 'application virtualization' - solving this problem is one of the reasons it exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you find, in your unstated application, that you cannot, try installing the new version on a virtual pc.

it also might pay to state why you want to do this?